# check if_null statement don't work

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, ifnull

I simply want to check, if a query give me 'NULL' as the result.

```
    $check = '  SELECT some_data FROM user
                WHERE condition = my_condition LIMIT 1';
                if ( is_null($check) )
    {        
    echo "yep, it's null";
    }
```

But i don't get the echo. The query definitly gives me the result 'NULL'. Whats wrong?

Comment: You're not executing the query though.... `is_null($check)` will always be false, because it's a string.

Comment: You need to execute the query, then fetch a row of results, then access the column from the result row.

Comment: stupid me! You're all right. I do the execution and fetch the results. Everything works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just execute the query and fetch a row of results.